# Hiding Keyboard on Android crashes app

Tags: java, android, crash, android-context, android-input-method

When I try to run this line in order to hide the keyboard (I get the InputMethodManager):

```
this.context = context;
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); //this line crashes the app
```

What should I do to fix it?
(I am running it from a fragment by the way)

**Crash Log:**

```
11-03 16:20:26.700: D/AndroidRuntime(2809): Shutting down VM
11-03 16:20:26.700: W/dalvikvm(2809): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at co.emuze.tabtest1.Tab1$1.onClick(Tab1.java:32)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-03 16:20:26.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2809):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Full on click method:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                text1.setText(editText1.getText().toString());
                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText1.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
```

Comment: plz add crash log with question

Comment: plz make sure `context` is not null  and u have problem in Tab1.java:32 line also add on button click code

Comment: line 32 is the line i said in the questions has a problem in it

Comment: share more code from button click  because these two lines fine but depend on where u are using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear context is null - you show the line `this.context = context`, and if the right hand side `context` is not a variable local to that method you're doing nothing. I think what you may be looking for is `context = getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 1):

**Dont forget to use try catch blog because in case when your keyboard not open and if you use key key board hide code app crashed**

User below code in Fragment

```
 try {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
       }
```